# Formula Automatically Appears

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large pricing sheet, in which I allocate costs in each year depending on how long my program runs during that year.

To distill this further, I have column C labeled "Days" and column D labeled "Cost." I manually enter the number of days in column C and column D then multiplies the number of days (column C) by costs per day.

The blank cell below the last entry in column D does not contain a formula (I did not copy down as it creates DIV errors elsewhere), however when I enter the number of days in column C, the adjacent empty cell in D automatically fills with the correct equation (again, it was blank before). I've noticed that this only happens when the last filled equation in D is in Accounting format as opposed to a custom one.

Is this typical? Does Excel auto copy downward when using certain number formats? I actually don't mind the action but it's thrown me for a loop.

**EDIT**
I've checked and it seems that the figures are not part of table. Here are two screen shots. The first and third column are days, the second and fourth are costs. In the second picture the highlighted formula was not present before.

Blank
[image: Blank Cell]

Filled
[image: Filled Cell]

Comment: [tag:excel-formula] is on-topic for SO.  However, you should include a screenshot of what you are experiencing to get the best answer.

Comment: The formatting shouldn't make any difference. IIRC you need at least 4 rows of data before the autofilling of formulas kicks in (assuming you haven't turned the option off).

Comment: I also wanted to ask if you have the columns organized as a table. If so, the excel would auto-fill formulas.

Comment: as Bob the Builder mentioned, tables will auto-populate formulas down a column.  You can determine if it's a table by clicking on a cell inside the table and then checking if a new "Table Tools" ribbon appears in the toolbar.  Also, if you are concerned with `#DIV/0!` errors, try using `=IFERROR()` around your equation and you can "format" the errors out.

Comment: Right-click the worksheet's name tab and choose *View Code**. When the VBE opens, do you have a worksheet code page with sub procedure event macros like the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro?

Comment: I have often noticed this behaviour, and have become resigned to Excel presuming to do what it thinks best. Even if I delete these auto-formulae, they sometimes (!) reappear.

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl+1, and set the cell format to general. 
It happened to me a couple of times where the formula was entered in to a cell that is formatted text. Maybe this is the case.